# Static and non-static methods in scala

Tags: scala, static, non-static

As we know we don't have static methods in scala. If we have to achieve that taste we declare that class as object. But the problem is that when we declare class as object then all methods present in that object becomes static. And in class all methods all non-static. What I want is that to have static as well as  non static methods in the same class, Is it possible? Definitely it would be possible but how??????

Comment: Which leads you to this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179390/what-are-the-advantages-of-scalas-companion-objects-vs-static-methods

Answer (score 3):

To do what you are trying do in Scala you create an `object` and a `class` of same name. Put static in `object` and instance members in `Class` version of it. This `object` is called a companion object.